# Why does C++ allow type has no-default constructor for std::map while not std::pair?

Tags: c++

Check the following `C++` code:

```
#include <string>
#include <map>

class A
{
public:
    A (int a) {};
};

int main()
{

    std::map<std::string, A> p;
    return 0;
}
```

The compilation is successful. While change `std::map` to `std::pair`:

```
#include <string>
#include <utility>

class A
{
public:
    A (int a) {};
};

int main()
{

    std::pair<std::string, A> p;
    return 0;
}
```

The compiler will complain:

```
$ clang++ test.cpp
In file included from test.cpp:1:
In file included from /usr/bin/../lib64/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/7.3.0/../../../../include/c++/7.3.0/string:40:
In file included from /usr/bin/../lib64/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/7.3.0/../../../../include/c++/7.3.0/bits/char_traits.h:39:
In file included from /usr/bin/../lib64/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/7.3.0/../../../../include/c++/7.3.0/bits/stl_algobase.h:64:
/usr/bin/../lib64/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/7.3.0/../../../../include/c++/7.3.0/bits/stl_pair.h:219:18: error: no matching
      constructor for initialization of 'A'
      : first(), second() { }
                 ^
test.cpp:13:31: note: in instantiation of member function 'std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, A>::pair'
      requested here
    std::pair<std::string, A> p;
                              ^
test.cpp:7:5: note: candidate constructor not viable: requires single argument 'a', but no arguments were provided
    A (int a) {};
    ^
test.cpp:4:7: note: candidate constructor (the implicit copy constructor) not viable: requires 1 argument, but 0 were
      provided
class A
      ^
1 error generated.
```

Why does `C++` allow type has no-default constructor for `std::map` while not `std::pair`?

Comment: Because the default constructor of `std::map` doesn't call the default constructor of its elements, while `std::pair` does

Comment: IIRC, the only part of `std::map` that needs an element's default constructor is the `[]` operator, and you can use `std::map` without ever using that.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`std::map` is empty when constructed, which means that it does not need to construct an `A` just yet. The `std::pair`, on the other hand, has to do it in order to complete its initialization.

Since both are class templates, only the member functions you use are actually instantiated. If you want to see the error you expect, you need to have the map try to construct a default `A`, for example:

```
int main()
{
    std::map<std::string, A> p;

    p[""];
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The difference is due to `A` not being default-constructible. The pair case picks this up immediately as it will attempt to default-construct an `A` instance.

Eventually the map case will yield the same error. You can see this if you write `p["Hello"];`:

```
int main()
{
    std::map<std::string, A> p;
    p["Hello"]; // oops - default constructor required here for `A`
}
```

Comment: "_Eventually the map case will yield the same error._" Well, not, necessarily, eventually. If you don't use `std::map::operator[]` (e.g. by using `std::map::insert` for element insertion, and `std::map::find` for lookup), one can use `std::map` to store values of types that don't have default constructors.